# Regular expression in JavaScript, always ‘undefined’ if use a grouping followed by a question mark

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

What I'm trying to do is to extract matching patterns, but one of the patterns could be optional. Let's go example directly.

The target text I'm trying to match would be,

```
<foo>\n<bar>\n#####<foo>\n#####<bar>
```

And my regular expression is,

```
/(#{5})?/
```

(*The reason why I use ? here is because the particular pattern could be optional. For example I don't want the match to be totally a miss rather than just an 'undefined' for this very pattern.*)

What I expected as returned by str.match() is,

```
[ '#####',
  '#####',
  index: 12,
  input: '<foo>\n<bar>\n#####<foo>\n#####<bar>' ]
```

But actually it's,

```
[ '',
  undefined,
  index: 0,
  input: '<foo>\n<bar>\n#####<foo>\n#####<bar>' ]
```

If I use following pattern instead, it'll work fine.

```
/(#{5})+/
```

Why?

I tried this in both nodejs/chrome and IE but neither one work which means this behavior is consistent across JS engine. But it doesn't behave the same way one of many tools i tried, [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/). I'm not sure if that's the tool's own issue or just different implementation.

Comment: I would guess that, if you make the pattern completely optional, then it's willing to match absolutely nothing at all (that is, the empty string). Why it doesn't go on after that to match your pattern, I do not know.

Comment: Regex is greedy, so it should find the longest possible match, which means it should return the matched string when it's optional.

Comment: Actually, have you tried using `/g` to make it global? Perhaps that is related.

Comment: @ChrisHayes That seems to be it. If you use /g you get lots of `""` matches with a couple of `#####` mixed in. Since it's optional, it's matching the empty string between each character. And without /g, it's matching the empty string at the beginning of the test string.

Comment: this is not the case with other flavours like java,.net

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It, thanks for verifying that. I'm just looking at JS for now.

Comment: @Barmar, I tried global before posting the question. But I suppose if JS is conservative on matching optional patterns, we'll always get nothing because it's optional, not just grouping case, right? And if you change the original text to "#####<foo>\n#####<bar>", you'll get the match which means the engine is working as greedy as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var re = /(#{5})/;
console.log ("<foo>\n<bar>\n#####<foo>\n#####<bar>".match (re));
console.log ("<foo>\n<bar>\nfoo>\n<bar>".match (re));
```

output:

```
[ '#####',
  '#####',
  index: 12,
  input: '<foo>\n<bar>\n#####<foo>\n#####<bar>' ]
null
```

If it's optional the regexp fails when there's no match and if it fails it returns null.

```
> /a/.exec("a")
[ 'a', index: 0, input: 'a' ]
> /a/.exec("b")
null
> "a".match(/a/)
[ 'a', index: 0, input: 'a' ]
> "b".match(/a/)
null
```

Also, don't use String#match(), it's slower than RegExp#exec() and both return the same:

[match() vs exec()](http://jsperf.com/string-match-vs-regexp-test/3)

Comment: In that case no optional pattern would match anything coz regular expression engine could always just return null, not just this case, right?

Comment: Yes, exec() and match() return null when there's no match. Also, don't use match(), it's slower than exec(). See my answer.

Comment: @ChundongWang Optional patterns are useful when they're combined with other patterns, especially between other patterns. For instance, if you want to match dates like "November 14, 2012" and "Nov 14th, 2012", you can use the pattern `/Nov(ember)? 14(th)?, 2012/`. But an optional pattern by itself will return null unless it matches something at the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Barmar, I agree that optional patterns needs to be used with other patterns. The question I posted here is not what I use in real world but simplified for Stackoverflow. But it's still undefined even if I combined it with other patterns in real cases.

Let's take your pattern for example. /Nov(ember)? 14(th)?, 2012/ will get a match for "Nov 14th, 2012", that's for sure. But it won't get a match for "Nov\n 14th, 2012" even with pattern /Nov(\n|ember)? 14(th)?, 2012/.